# Javascrip; d3.js - why cant i create an Heatmap?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to create a Heatmap. But what i can do its just to show one rectangle. whats wrong in my code? Ive tried many Things, but still its not working. Can Anyone help me with this?

There arent any error in my code, buts still its wrong. der rectangel should be filled with different colours.
Here is my current Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <p>First Tutorial</p>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
  <div id="container"> </id>
  <script>

    /* JavaScript */
    var data = [
      [2.56, 8.52, 4.92, 2.58, 8.44, 2.29],
      [7.94, 8.42, 7.71, 7.0, 8.13, 5.63],
      [1.38, 3.29, 2.38, 2.85, 1.38, 1.77],
      [1.31, 2.48, 1.04, 1.21, 1.83, 1.48],
      [1.58, 8.19, 4.75, 3.38, 4.83, 1.46],
      [4.48, 4.08, 4.13, 1.73, 1.37, 2.58], ];

    var rowLabels = [
      "rowOne",
      "rowTwo",
      "rowThree",
      "rowFour",
      "rowFive",
      "rowSix",
    ];
    var columnLabels = [
      "columnOne",
      "columnTwo",
      "columnThree",
      "columnFour",
      "columnFive",
      "columnSix",
    ];

    const mapData = data.reduce((res, item, index) => {
      const group = rowLabels[index];
      item.forEach((value, colIndex) => {
        res.min = Math.min(value, res.min);
        res.max = Math.max(value, res.max);
        res.data.push({group, variable: columnLabels[colIndex], value});
      });
      return res;
    }, {data: [], min: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, max: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY});

    /* Layout constants */
    var margin = {top: 0, right:0, bottom: 90, left: 80},
      width = 960- margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    /* Initialization of SVG graphics */
    var svg = d3.select("#container")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      //X Scale and Axis:
      var x= d3.scaleBand()
      .range([ 0, width ])
      .domain(columnLabels)
      .padding(0.01);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10,10) rotate(-45)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("font-size", 10)
    
    // Y scales and Axis:
    var y= d3.scaleBand()
      .range([ height, 0 ])
      .domain(rowLabels)
      .padding(0.01);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

      var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["#0000ff", "#00ff00"])
  .domain([mapData.min,mapData.max])

  svg.selectAll()
      .data(mapData.data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
      .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you have deleted your previous post? If you expect people to help you, respect the time they invest to answer your questions...

Comment: BTW, "your current code" worked perfectly in the snippet. Just check everything carefully when you copy and paste...

Comment: Consider editing your question to include a description of the problem that you are trying to resolve.